# Pegando dados ocultos com a tag <noscript> com file_get_contents

Tags: php, javascript, html, https, file-get-contents

Gostaria de recuperar as informações de um CAPTCHA de um formulário e exibí-lo em outra utilizando o `file_get_contents`.

Ocorre que a página onde os dados estão possuem a tag `<noscript>` que avisa:

> "Por favor habilite o JavaScript do seu navegador para que o serviço
>   de captcha funcione corretamente."

o que impede que os dados sejam recuperados com o `file_get_contents`.

Existe alguma função ou outro jeito de recuperar esses dados emulando o javascript habilitado?

O Site é esse:

> https://www2.dataprev.gov.br/sabiweb/consulta/inicio.view#sabiweb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há como "emular um javascript habilitado", exceto que use algum Webdriver, porém você não precisa emular.

Analisando rapidamente o código fonte o captcha é gerado em [/sabiweb/captcha-load/](https://www2.dataprev.gov.br/sabiweb/captcha-load/), ele contem o value do captcha (o ID dele) e também o caminho da imagem e do áudio, mas você pode também obter apenas os cabeçalhos, nele terá o `JSESSIONID` que é o mesmo  valor.

Logo, você está fazendo a requisição para o lado errado e acho que isso nem sequer é preciso, mas enfim.

---

Isto seria suficiente para obter tal código, ignorando problemas de segurança:

```
if($captchaJS = file_get_contents('https://www2.dataprev.gov.br/sabiweb/captcha-load/')){

    preg_match('/([0-9A-Za-z\.\-_]{90,})/', $captchaJS, $achados);

    $Codigo = $achados['0'];
    $Cookie = substr($Codigo, strpos($Codigo, '_', 3) + 1);

}
```

Assim, basta que utilize:

```
https://www2.dataprev.gov.br/sabiweb/api/imagem?d= . $Codigo
```

Para carregar a imagem. Já para enviar o formulário utilize o valor do `$Codigo` e os cookies do `$Cookie`.

---

*Mas, acho que você nem sequer precisa disso.*